# NodeJS read stream returns undefined

Tags: node.js

I am trying to read a file about 1GB (PI number with a billion decimal places) using nodeJS stream, but I am getting undefined when logging. Am I missing something?

```
import fs from "fs";

const read = (file) => {

  const readStream = fs.createReadStream(file, 'utf-8');

  readStream.on('error', (error) => {
      console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
  })

  readStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
      return chunk.toString();
  })
}

const pi = read('pi.txt');
console.log(pi, 'pi');
```

Comment: That's not how streams and asynchronous code works. Your `read()` function is returning nothing. If you want a quick fix, just use `fs.readFileSync()`.

Comment: @robertklep readFileSync returns an error because the file is too big

Comment: read is just the function name

Comment: If the file is too big for `readFileSync()`, using a stream to read it entirely into memory will not work either.

Comment: So what's the solution? @robertklep

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? Your code is just showing you reading the file and showing its contents, if that's all you want to do then you can use `fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(process.stdout)`.